# magento: some values for an attribute are not being saved

Tags: magento

I have a color attribute with a lot of colors in it.
If I update a value AFTER a specific row(red arrow in image) the value won't save but if I update a value before that specific row then the value gets updated and saves correctly.
I've been trying to figure this out but can't get anywhere.
What might be causing this issue?
I'm using Magento 1.9.1.0
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Check PHP configuration (`php.ini`) and increase [max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars). Default value is `1000` which does not seem enough.

You can easily check your PHP configuration with `phpinfo();`.

Make sure you also check `post_max_size` setting since so many input fields will increase request size.

Best of luck.